# Updating physics body when animating with SKAction moveTo

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I have a 'bar' moving back and forth, I have correctly gotten it to move the sprite from right to left. However It seems that the physics body is still in the same place as it was originally. I can make contact with the 'bar' even when it has animated away.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
- (void)setupBars
{
    leftBar = [BarNode new];
    leftBar.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    leftBar.name = @"leftBar";
    leftBar.size = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 50);
    [leftBar setPosition:CGPointMake(0, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 275)];
    leftBar.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:leftBar.size];
    leftBar.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    leftBar.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = nodeBitMask;
    [self addChild:leftBar];


    rightBar = [BarNode new];
    rightBar.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    rightBar.name = @"rightBar";
    rightBar.size = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 50);
    [rightBar setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 275)];
    rightBar.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:rightBar.size];
    rightBar.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    rightBar.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = nodeBitMask;
    [self addChild:rightBar];

    SKAction *moveLeftBar = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(-160, leftBar.position.y) duration:1];
    SKAction *back = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(0, leftBar.position.y) duration:1];
    SKAction *all = [SKAction sequence:@[moveLeftBar, back]];
    SKAction *repeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:all];
    [leftBar runAction:repeat];

    moveLeftBar = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 160, rightBar.position.y) duration:1];
    back = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), rightBar.position.y) duration:1];
    all = [SKAction sequence:@[moveLeftBar, back]];
    repeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:all];
    [rightBar runAction:repeat];


}
```

Comment: Post the code for creating leftBar.

Comment: @sangony Ok posted, the code in `BarNode` just sets the texture to an image.

Comment: and you're saying that the physics body stays in place even after the image/texture has moved away? Did you set skView.showsPhysics = YES ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem that my boxes line up, can you check my lines where I set the physics body?

Comment: I can't run your code. Have you set to show physics and does the physics box line up with your image/texture? Also, what happens to the physics body when you run your animation?

Comment: The physics box doesn't line up but it does follow a similar movement. Here is a video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEXThhDbNFg&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @sangony It has something to do with setting the anchor point. Any ideas?

Comment: Anchor point move texture around the node's position...Actually physics body is properly positioned but your texture isn't.  Default anchor point is (0.5, 0.5). Just remove those lines where you setting anchor point and you will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

You pretty much already answered your own question. Just wanted you to get there yourself. The problem with SpriteKit's physics bodies is that they do not react to a change in anchor points. They are always based on 0.5,0.5 regardless of what you set your node's anchor point to.

Your options are to either modify your node to use a default anchor point (0.5, 0.5) or use a `(SKPhysicsBody *)bodyWithRectangleOfSize:(CGSize)s center:(CGPoint)center` which lets you set the center coordinates.